# Is there a difference between the constraints instantiated in these two ways?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm rather new to iOS programming.

I was wondering if there is any functional difference between making a constraint like this

```
cell_image_view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 60).isActive = true
```

As opposed to doing it this way

```
var my_constraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell_image_view, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 60)
    
cell_image_view.addConstraint(my_constraint)
```

Anyone have any insights into this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`heightAnchor` is a `UIView` property that returns an `NSLayoutDimension` anchor, which is a subclass of `NSLayoutAnchor`.

If you search in the Xcode docs under, you'll find the following:

> NSLayoutAnchor: A factory class for creating layout constraint objects
> using a fluent API.

Layout anchors are "[**Syntactic sugar**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar)" for creating `NSLayoutConstraint` objects. Assuming you have them set up to create the same constraints, the results are the same.